# In Sublime Text 3 how do I install the Lua build system?

Tags: build, lua, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Apparently the other posts I looked at didn't work for me

Lua installation: nil

Test file: http://prntscr.com/9kr5dv

Build system:

```
{
    "cmd": ["lua", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(?:(?:\t)|(?:.+: ))(.+):([0-9]+): (.*)$",
"selector": "source.lua"
}
```

Preferences:

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}

{
    "additional_path_items" : ["~/Documents"]
}
```

Comment: Anybody know what I should do?

Comment: If you run from the command line `lua myfile.lua` does it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you can run lua from the command line.
2. Make sure that you create and save your `.sublime-build` in you sublime User folder. The configuration looks correct to me.
3. You don't need to change anything in your Preferences.sublime-settings and please make sure that you have valid json in there.

After all go to your file and press `Ctrl + B` and it should work.